# text-shadow (and other css3) causes scroll lag

Tags: performance, css

I've noticed that the more I use certain CSS3 elements (namely `box-shadow` and `text-shadow`) the more scroll lag exists on a page. I notice the problem on both FF4 and Chrome 10. Is there any good way to measure this or reduce it? I want good performance, but I also want to be able to use the shadows to create dimensionality between the various elements.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've found the two biggest offenders (as far as performance goes) are the blur amount of your shadows and whether you're using any alphas (rgba, hsl, etc).

Hardware acceleration is key to using any of the css3 goodies and maintaining acceptable performance. Webkit (not sure about FF4) won't even use the GPU unless you specifically ask for a three-dimensional operation. You can kick in the GPU for any element by simply applying a 0-pixel 3d transform:

```css
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
/* OR */
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

Paul Irish has a [great talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q_O9_C2ZjoA) on css3 performance and using webkits dev flags to debug GPU rendering.

From terminal (OS X), you can launch Safari with the GPU rendering debug flag with this:

```
CA_COLOR_OPAQUE=1 /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari
```

This will show you (in translucent red) which DOM regions are being rendered on the GPU and which ones are rendered by the CPU [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79ZRg.png).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the `-webkit-transform` workaround no longer works in Chrome and MS Edge. (Both are based on Blink, which forked from WebKit in 2013.) But Firefox and Safari seem to handle `text-shadow` just fine now without any lag.

I was able to avoid `text-shadow` lag by using `drop-shadow()` instead:

```css
.shadow {
  /* text-shadow: 1px 2px 4px black; */
  filter: drop-shadow(1px 2px 4px black);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="shadow">Item 1</li>
  <li class="shadow">Item 2</li>
  <li class="shadow">Item 3</li>
</ul>

<ul class="shadow" style="background: pink">
  <li>Effect of applying <code>drop-shadow</code> to an entire div</li>
  <li><code>drop-shadow</code> is based on the alpha mask of the entire element</li>
</ul>
```

The only limit here is you'll need to set the `filter` on every individual content element, rather than on one root element. Otherwise, the shadow applies to the whole element like a `box-shadow`, if it has an opaque background.

Check out MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow