# Is CSS's efficiency with text-shadow as bad as box-shadow?

Tags: css, performance, box-shadow

I have noticed in my many years of web design that CSS's box shadow is enormously expensive with resources and causes many old phones to lag severely; but is that is the case with text-shadow? When is it okay to use text-shadow, and how is it rendered?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it was. But I am indeed curious if they use e.g. similar blurring and color composition algorithms.

Comment: @BoltClock ...at least you can fake box shadow with relatively few tags. I was incredibly surprised nobody else asked this question. Perhaps I (or we) should look at the source code, but I have no idea where to get access to that.

Comment: I bet it's even more expensive, since the shapes of the characters are more complex than rectangles.

Comment: Many browsers are completely Free & Open Source, so you can download the sources to them, including all the libraries, at least for Linux. Example: http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/41.0.1/source/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> CSS's box shadow is enormously expensive with resources and causes many old phones to lag severely; but is that is the case with text-shadow?

I guess the short answer is yes: text-shadow is expensive for the same reasons box-shadow is.

It looks like this article confirms that text-shadow can cause performance issues (at least for elements with frequent re-renders): http://codeincomplete.com/posts/2011/8/11/noglow/.

There is also this question that seems related and has an accepted answer: [text-shadow (and other css3) causes scroll lag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811974/text-shadow-and-other-css3-causes-scroll-lag).

> When is it okay to use text-shadow

I guess this depends on your audience and wether they have powerful enough hardware.

> …and how is it rendered?

This seems to ask for implementation details which are probably browser/platform-specific, …and probably irrelevant to the question for the most part. :)